# How to change linux terminal to yaft on boot

Tags: boot, terminal, arch-linux

I am using Arch Linux on an old laptop and when I log in it is to `$TERM=linux`. How do I configure it to load [yaft](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/yaft/) instead? At the moment I have to log in then type `yaft` but I would like to use yaft as the default terminal (for the colours).

Answer (score 2):

An easy fix for that would be to insert a line into `.bash_profile` that starts yaft if `$TERM=linux`. Something like

```
case "$TERM" in
  linux)
    exec yaft
    ;;
esac
```

should do just fine.
If you don't want to do it via bash, you would have to change the default application that is started by login, `man chsh` might help you there.